# How to import knowledge base article ratings value

Tags: knowledge

can we import knowledge base article ratings value(1-5) using Data loder or import articles or workbench?

We have a business scenario where we need to import ratings for more than 10k articles.

Answer (score 0):

You can workbench to retrieve the csv list. There are two ways to achieve that:

**Using Vote Object:**

```
 select id, parentid, type, CreatedById from vote where parent.type='ayb__Article__ka' 

**Replace Type with your article type...
```

**Using KnowledgeArticleVoteStat Object:**

```
 SELECT Channel, NormalizedScore, ParentId FROM KnowledgeArticleVoteStat where Channel='App'
```

Comment: I believe we can only query all the values. Is there way to import/Insert rating values with a respective parentId(articleId) from excel sheet? –